# Image not displaying using encoded content

Tags: javascript, html, image, extjs, extjs6

I am trying to display an image in my ExtJS grid using encoded gif with base64 as follows

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
```

As far as I know, this should display an image as the actual contents are encoded in the hash. But the image is not displaying,

If I give actual path of any other image, the image displays-

```
<img src="myapplication/images/someimage.png"/>
```

What I am doing wrong here?
**I am using ExtJs6**

Answer (score 0):

You provide base64 of empty gif with size 1x1 pixel. It can be lookt as no image display.  Try this HTML, it's work fine for me:

```
<img style="width: 22px; height: 22px;" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

Comment: This is working for other images. I am trying to use Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL. For this image it is not working,